# Passing compiler command line to preprocessor using CMake

Tags: compiler-construction, cmake, c-preprocessor

I have a CMake project that I want to be able to compile using g++, MinGW/g++ (4.x each), Clang (3.x) and MSVC++ (>= V8).

I want to have a precompiler symbol with the compiler arguments or command line.

This is useful to see whether optimization was enabled and which switches were enabled at the command line.

E.g. a program compiled with `g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -g0` should know that the flags are `"-O3 -DNDEBUG -g0"`.
When writing manual Makefiles, I could simply collect the flags in a variable and then additionally pass this to the compiler yielding a command line `g++ -O3 -DNDEBUG -g0 -DCOMPILER_ARGS="-O3 -DNDEBUG -g0"`.

How can I achieve this using CMake?

Comment: Do you _need_ to have then defined in a preprocessor macro? How would you use the preprocessor macro in the code/program? Is that information only necessary for debugging purposes for developers? Or does it actually need to be used in your executable/library's funcionality? i.e. Is this an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? It sounds a bit like your X is to get preprocessor macros, but your Y is "_to see whether optimization was enabled and which switches were enabled at the command line._"

Comment: In your build, do any of the source files that get linked into the same target have differing compiler flags than each other? Or do all your source files that are part of a single target get the exact same compiler flags?

Answer (score 0):

For all options except MSVC, rather than creating a preprocessor definition, you should probably just use `make VERBOSE=1` when building or add

```
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt.

For MSVC, you can examine each project's command line arguments from within the IDE: Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line and Property Pages -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line.

Comment: @Manuel need a way to pass compile flags to the program, if i get him right. You are proposing him to copy-paste it manually?

Comment: Well, I'm suggesting that it's pretty unorthodox to have the command parameters held in a project as a preprocessor definition.

Answer (score -1):

`add_definitions("-DCOMPILER_ARGS=\"${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}\")`

But be aware, that `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable contains only flags set by user. If you wish whole set of compile flags, use target property `COMPILE_FLAGS`. This value can be obtained by `get_target_property()` function.

Comment: -1 `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is not empty by default on Windows.  Also this misses all the flags held in the configuration-specific variables like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`.

Comment: Okay, i didn't said that it's empty on windows. And i said that `COMPILE_FLAGS` have all flags. Anyway, thanks for -1, now my reputation is round.

Comment: You said "`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable contains only flags set by user".  That's not always the case.

Comment: I don't think the target `COMPILE_FLAGS` property has all the flags either.  And I get a -1 to my rep for giving you a -1, so it's almost the same :-)